# Remove clickable space around play image inside red border

Tags: javascript, html, css

On this code you are not able to click on the area around the play image inside the red border.

**Code 1** https://jsfiddle.net/93pza8r2/

How would I do that with this code?

https://jsfiddle.net/k3ba87fg/

How do I make the area inside the red border not clickable, like how it is in **Code 1**?

That is what I am trying to do.

[image]

```js
const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
(function manageCurtain() {
  "use strict";

   function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");

  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
      curtain.classList.add("fadeout");
 
    }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  "use strict";
  
    let player = null;
  
  const tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }
  let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    const shufflePlaylist = true;

    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {

    const playlist = "M7lc1UVf-VE";

    new YT.Player(video, {

      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1,
        loop: 1,
        rel: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        fs: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        playlist
      },
      events: {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function play() {
    player.playVideo();
  }
  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const wrapper = cover.parentElement ;
    const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}

(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.parentElement;
    show(wrapper);
  }

  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.fadeout .slide-wrap {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

.slide .slide-wrap {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;

}

.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;

}

.slide-wrap:before,
.slide-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 5s linear;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide-wrap:before {
  left: 0;

}

.slide-wrap:after {
  right: 0;

}


.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*background: red;*/
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  cursor: pointer;

}


.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.wrap,
.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);

}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="tcell">
    <div class="curtain-wrapper">
      <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
        <div class="curtain">

          <div class="video-wrapper">
            <div class="video-ratio-keeper">

              <div class="wrap">
                <div class="video video-frame"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="slide-wrap fadeout"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="jacket" title="Play">
          <svg class="play" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
              M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
          </svg></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need move up your play button above `class="jacket"` ,  in JS assign `class="play"` instead `class="jacket"` and in css style add this:

```
.jacket {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The Better way remove `class="jacket"` from html and css. [reference](https://jsfiddle.net/Jnetc/vw164s9b/)

```js
const cover = document.querySelector('.play'); // This line
(function manageCurtain() {
  'use strict';

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove('hide');
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add('hide');
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    console.log(cover);
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector('.curtain');
    curtain.classList.add('slide');
    curtain.classList.add('fadeout');
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector('.play'); // This line
  cover.addEventListener('click', coverClickHandler);
})();

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  'use strict';

  let player = null;

  const tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }
  let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    const shufflePlaylist = true;

    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {
    const playlist = 'M7lc1UVf-VE';

    new YT.Player(video, {
      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1,
        loop: 1,
        rel: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        fs: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        playlist,
      },
      events: {
        onReady: onPlayerReady,
        onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
      },
    });
  }

  function play() {
    player.playVideo();
  }
  return {
    addPlayer,
  };
})();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
  const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector('.video');
  videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}

(function iife() {
  'use strict';

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove('hide');
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.parentElement;
    show(wrapper);
  }

  cover.addEventListener('click', coverClickHandler);
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.fadeout .slide-wrap {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

.slide .slide-wrap {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
}

.slide-wrap:before,
.slide-wrap:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 5s linear;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1500/1500) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide-wrap:before {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-wrap:after {
  right: 0;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*background: red;*/
  border-radius: 25px;
  pointer-events: none; /* This line*/
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.wrap,
.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="tcell">
        <div class="curtain-wrapper">
          <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
            <div class="curtain">
              <div class="video-wrapper">
                <div class="video-ratio-keeper">
                  <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="video video-frame"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="slide-wrap fadeout"></div>
            </div>

            <svg class="play" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
              <path
                d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z"
              />
            </svg>
            <!-- <div class="jacket" title="Play"></div>  this line -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an overlay over your container having background as transparent
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
And place your play button over this overlay in the middle using flex properties.
And now when you click on play button, destroy the overlay.